# How to fill a gridview in XML

Tags: android, xml, gridview, view, adapter

I have a gridview that just needs to hold 4 buttons, how ever I keep getting an operation not supported in AdapterView error when executing. Can you even fill a gridview through xml?

Comment: Show us the code snippet where you are adding the 4 buttons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot add children to a `GridView` in XML. You need to create an appropriate `Adapter` and associate it with the `GridView` via `setAdapter()`.

Most likely, if you only have four buttons, you do not want a `GridView` in the first place.

Comment: ug, I was hoping you wouldn't say that. I know that I could use the RelativeView, but I'm not sure how to align the four of them in the upper most middle of the screen at that point. Any suggestions?